# Authentication error while connecting Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a new collection and get `MongoDB connection error: { MongoError: Authentication failed.` error

```
require("dotenv").config()
const mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const dbRoute = `mongodb://${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_ADMIN}:${
  process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD
}>@${process.env.REACT_APP_DB}`

mongoose.connect(dbRoute, { useNewUrlParser: true })

let db = mongoose.connection

db.once("open", () => console.log("connected to the database"))

// checks if connection with the database is successful
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"))
```

`REACT_APP_SERVER_ADMIN` is one of the `Users` from mlab db and `REACT_APP_SERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD` is the password that I used when I created it in mlab dashboard.

`REACT_APP_DB` is in the format `<...>.mlab.com:PORT/DBNAME`

There isn't any schema or a model defined as of now.

Nothing complex about this as far as I can see so I am probably missing something basic. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(dbRoute)`?

Comment: There was a typo. -_- `>` in the dbRoute url.